# Jquery .Submit() is not triggering submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, form-submit, jquery-events

I have a very small problem,

I want to submit my code using jQuery on dropdown change:

```
 $("#mydropDown").change(function(){           
        $("#myForm").submit();
    });
```

but it is not submitting.

I also fired following code in Firebug console:

```
$("#myForm").submit();
```

it given me this output

`[form#myForm]`

I'm not getting what is the problem... :o?

Comment: try $("#myForm")[0].submit();

Comment: <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm" method="post" action="mypage">
<select id="myDropDown" >Options</select>
</form>

Comment: Do you have any submit event bound to this form? event handlers may prevent default submit actions if it returns false or invokes `preventDefault` method on event object. try to see jQuery bound event handler via `$._data($('#myForm')[0]).events.submit`

Comment: @jay > $("#myForm")[0].submit(); returns undefined method in console

Comment: Isn't `mydropDown` typo of `myDropDown`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be, you have another event bound, if want cleaning up:

```
 $("#mydropDown").change(function(){           
        $("#myForm").unbind().submit();
    });
```

make sure that is within

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //....
})
```

Comment: srry, its "unbind()" no "remove()", srry.
$("#myForm").unbind().submit();

Comment: I'm doing with this it removes form but showing when I reload also I'm getting post values.... thanks levi...

Answer (score 3):

hi that time I used unbind but I really wanted to find to why it is happening. later 
I found answer of this question. I'm not much sure it is correct or not but it worked for me. **In the same form ('#myForm') there is a submit button with id='submit' and name='submit'.**
I changed both to submit_btn and it worked for me hope it may help...

Thank you for your support!!!

Answer (score 2):

You may have another event bound to your form that is cancelling the submit event.

To check this, you could execute the following in the console:

```
console.log($('#myForm').data('events'));
```

Which will output all events bound to your form.

Comment: >>> console.log($('#myForm').data('events'));

emply line showing below

Comment: @Ravi then something else is happening, check Johnny's answer for a debug method.

Comment: @Jashwant glad you like it, it's helped me out in similar situations :)

Answer (score 0):

The jquery is pretty basic so it must be something else.  To debug this I would just comment out all the jquery and see if you can get the form to submit with just a submit button.

If that doesnt work it would look at your action page.